# Custom ESLint rule for Redux reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux and Redux Toolkit in combination with ESLint.

When I implement my `extraReducers`, sometimes I don't require both the `state` and `action` property that Redux supplies, which in turn, makes ESLint throw an error.

Right now, I am manually disabling the linter rule for that specific line with this comment:

`// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars`

However, is there a way to rewrite the function declaration to avoid the linter rule, or can I globally disable the rule only for this case?

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    [fetch.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading"
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can leave out `action` param. But if unused param precedes used ones, then one option is to use [underscore syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern), which is quite common practice:

`const example = (_foo, bar) => console.log(bar);`

Answer (score 1):

You just don't need to declare parameters that you don't use. You can always add them in later.

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetch.pending]: () => {
      state.status = "loading"
    },
  },
})
```

is totally fine as well.